# Connecting to Google Drive API in Play Store app loops

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I set up an OAuth 2.0 client ID "MyApp-Debug" in the Google API console. I used my app's package name and the SHA1 key from the ~/.android/debug.keystore keystore.

I can connect and browse Google Drive just fine with the debug version of my app.

I also set up a client ID "MyApp-Release" in the console. I used the same package name and the SHA1 key from the keystore & password that I use when I run "Generate Signed APK" in Android Studio.

But for some reason the Drive connection fails with the release version of my app from the Play Store, and I keep getting the prompt to choose my account. Am I missing a step here? I didn't do anything with the Client ID it generated or the JSON file it created.

EDIT (I found some more information):

I sideloaded a debuggable release apk in an attempt to debug it, and it authorizes correctly using the release authorization (I removed the debug one to be certain). So I downloaded the derived APK from my Play Store account, and it looped just like the installed version. The Play Store is doing something to disable my Drive access. Any thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT:

[Here's the logcat output](https://gist.github.com/j8s0n/6fc7a5f80da4ef04c55df48ae6e22819), from just before I start the app until it fails to connect a couple times. I see some responses with API_UNAVAILABLE, which seems odd, since the Drive API is available. Also, when I look at the Drive API in the API Manager at console.developers.google.com, I don't see any requests for the attempts with the Play Store binaries, but I do see them when I connect from the debug or sideloaded release builds.